# SyntaxError when using $

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm learning Python via Jupyter Notebook.
I'd like to calculate x̄ from a set of data, then print out the value in a string. 
How do I get the variable x̄?

I've tried using $\bar x$  and $\overline {x}$   but both return a Syntax Error

Am I missing a library?
I have

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

```
f = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print($\bar x$ + f" = {np.average(f)}")

  File "<ipython-input-128-0e2d9b6ee635>", line 2
    print($\bar x$ + f" = {np.average(f)}")
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
f = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print($\overline {x}$ + f" = {np.average(f)}")

  File "<ipython-input-129-2807d1e5e7ae>", line 2
    print($\overline {x}$ + f" = {np.average(f)}")
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: what would you like to see at the end? if just the average str(np.average(f)) should work

Comment: I don't know much about Jupyter Notebook, but your snippets are indeed NOT valid python syntax. If your goal is to learn Python, you'll probably be better starting off with just the plain builtin python shell and the official tutorial - then it will be time to switch to IPython, Jupyter or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

**Use this instead:**

```
import numpy as np
f = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(f"{np.average(f)}")
```